# Using the Stripe API to allow a free trial of a single product in a multi-product subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

We have three products, small, medium and large. I'm using the Stripe API to charge customers on a prorated for each product they use every month.

I'd like new customers to be able to have a free 14 day trial of the first **small** product they add to their subscription.

Picture a VPS company allowing a free trial of their small VPS, but wanting to charge if a customer adds a medium and large one in the first month.

---

The problem I'm encountering is that free trials apply to all products in a subscription. If I use the `trial_period_days` attribute when creating a subscription or a checkout session, that applies to all products in that subscription for that month. i.e. customer adds a small product, then adds 100 large products, and receives all of them for free during the trial.

I've tried looking into coupons as an alternative, as in applying the cost of a small product to a customers subscription, but if they remove a product at any time from the subscription, the pro-rated refund excludes the coupon, and so the amount vanishes.

Is there any way to use the Stripe API to product the first product only with a free trial; while still only having one recurring subscription?

Comment: This is not really supported in Stripe no, trial periods are subscription-wide. You would have to experiment with coupons or negative invoice items(https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#Customize , items can have a `-100` `amount` for example) to try to achieve something like this.

Comment: As far as I can see a negative line item is not supported on an invoice, but negative invoice items are.